# Python Update all values of just the key name in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to update the key name in dictionary using python.

I tried a for loop like below, but it was basically overriding the values and not saving the values in a list format.

How can I recursively add it using a for loop, or is there any better approach for it?

```
for lstr_document_object in pdct_input_body["Input"]:
    lstr_document_object["DocumentType"] = lstr_document_object["ObjectType"]
    lstr_document_object["DocumentFormat"] = lstr_document_object["ObjectFormat"]
    lstr_document_object["DocumentSourceFileName"] = 
    lstr_document_object["ObjectSourceFileName"]
```

- For directly updating the value I tried using, but it resulted in no updation.

```
sample_dict['DocumentType'] = sample_dict.pop('ObjectType')
```

- Sample Input

```
{
  "Input": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "Document",
      "ObjectFormat": "pdf",
      "ObjectSourceFileName": "Mr.Dave_ICICI.pdf"
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "Document",
      "ObjectFormat": "pdf",
      "ObjectSourceFileName": "Mr.Dave_HDFC.pdf"
    }
  ],
  "Source": "Client",
  "ClientCode": "CL"
}
```

- Desired Output

```
{
  "Input": [
    {
      "DocumentType": "Document",
      "DocumentFormat": "pdf",
      "DocumentSourceFileName": "Mr.Dave_ICICI.pdf",
      "UUID": "<generated-uuid>"
    },
    {
      "DocumentType": "Document",
      "DocumentFormat": "pdf",
      "DocumentSourceFileName": "Mr.Dave_HDFC.pdf",
      "UUID": "<generated-uuid>"
    }
  ],
  "Source": "Client",
  "ClientCode": "CL"
}
```

Comment: I'd just copy the value `sample_dict['DocumentType'] = sample_dict['ObjectType']` and after that delete the original key value pair `del sample_dict['ObjectType']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try **json** modul, turn the dictionary to a json string, replace the key names, and then turn it back to a dictionary, e.g.

```
import json

adict = {'a':1, 'b':2}

>>> adict

{'a': 1, 'b': 2}

jsonstr = json.dumps(adict)

adict = json.loads(jsonstr.replace('a', 'c'))

>>> adict

{'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
data = {
  "Input": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "Document",
      "ObjectFormat": "pdf",
      "ObjectSourceFileName": "Mr.Dave_ICICI.pdf"
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "Document",
      "ObjectFormat": "pdf",
      "ObjectSourceFileName": "Mr.Dave_HDFC.pdf"
    }
  ],
  "Source": "Client",
  "ClientCode": "CL"
}


def replacer(x):
     return { k.replace("Object", "Document"): v for k,v in x.items()}
     
data["Input"] = [replacer(x) for x in data["Input"]]
```

It doesn't strictly "update", but replaces the "Input" part with a newly generated one, but I think it does what you wanted.